# Manipulate date with Excel macro screws locale format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a large xls file export with a column for dates that looks like this:

```
10-Ott-2019
11-Ott-2019
11-Ott-2019
11-Ott-2019
12-Ott-2019
14-Ott-2019
```

I need to change all the months to their number using a macro: i.e. "Ott" (October) to it's number (10)

```
Columns("AC:AC").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Ott", Replacement:="10", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, FormulaVersion:= _
        xlReplaceFormula2
```

and I would expect to receive this

```
10-10-2019
11-10-2019
11-10-2019
11-10-2019
12-10-2019
14-10-2019

...
```

but unfortunately excel screws the data with some sort of cell auto format and gives back this

```
 10-10-2019
 10-11-2019
 10-11-2019
 10-11-2019
 10-12-2019
 14-10-2019
```

Basically if the day is smaller or equal 12 excel take it as if it's the month number no matter what, it also ignores the system locale setting for date with is italian.

As a side note I don't need this to be formatted as a date, it could be a string and I'd be fine, but I don't want excel to change the dates.

Any ideas?

I also tried this macro:

```
Columns("AC:AC").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    Selection.Replace What:="Ott", Replacement:="10", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, FormulaVersion:= _
        xlReplaceFormula2
```

But the result is the same...

Comment: Did you try with `ReplaceFormat:=True`?

Comment: yes, it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Here you can download the xlsx I'm trying to fix, it's all blank except the column AC which present the issue (no macro included in this file): https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpfiaazyi4ud932/date_tofix.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

Excel automatically applies the data format to the cell according to the format of each data. Therefore, the correct result can be obtained only when the data values are correctly entered.

```
 Sub testSeveralMonth()
    Dim myDay() As String
    Dim vDB, vSplit
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, j As Integer
    Dim a, b
    Dim s As String
    
    a = Array("Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic")
    b = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
    
    vDB = Range("ac1", Range("ac" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim myDay(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(a)
            s = Replace(s, a(j), b(j))
        Next j
        If IsDate(s) Then
            vSplit = Split(s, "-")
            vDB(i, 1) = DateSerial(vSplit(2), vSplit(1), vSplit(0))
        End If
    Next i
   Range("ac:ac").NumberFormatLocal = "dd-mm-yyyy"
   Range("ac1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
   
End Sub
```

Example One Month

```
Sub test()
    Dim myDay() As String
    Dim vDB, vSplit
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    
    vDB = Range("ac1", Range("ac" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim myDay(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        myDay(i, 1) = Replace(vDB(i, 1), "Ott", 10)
        If IsDate(myDay(i, 1)) Then
            vSplit = Split(myDay(i, 1), "-")
            vDB(i, 1) = DateSerial(vSplit(2), vSplit(1), vSplit(0))
        End If
    Next i
   Range("ac1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
   Range("ac:ac").NumberFormatLocal = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End Sub
```

---

### result image

### [image]

### error code

```
Sub test2()
    Dim myDay() As String
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    
    vDB = Range("ac1", Range("ac" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim myDay(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To r
       vDB(i, 1) = Replace(vDB(i, 1), "Ott", 10)
    Next i
    Range("ac1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Range("ac:ac").NumberFormatLocal = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End Sub
```

---

### Error Image

[image]

Comment: I think you centered the issue, unfortunately your code gives a runtime error 9 "Subscript out of range (Error 9)" on this line: vDB(i, 1) = DateSerial(vSplit(2), vSplit(1), vSplit(0)). Also How can I replicate for all the months?

Comment: @DavideC, If you want to work with multiple months, you can create a loop that replaces letters and numbers for several months.

Comment: @DavideC, I edited answer for several months. I think the cause of the error was not only the data in October, but the data was in several months, so it seems that an error occurred because it could not be processed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the script now works the data is safe but excel prints dd-01-yyyy, dd-02-yyyy and so on

Comment: this is the template file I tested it on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpfiaazyi4ud932/date_tofix.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Go figure, I see that the date is printed wrong due to locale which is very weird behavior from microsoft as the date format needs to be translated to work, so this: Range("ac:ac").NumberFormatLocal = "dd-mm-yyyy" has to be Range("ac:ac").NumberFormatLocal = "gg-mm-aaaa" to work on an italian localized installation of excel

Answer (score 1):

This might work, if your dates are real dates and not strings.

```
Sub ReFormat()
    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    End With
    Columns("AC:AC").Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last macro yields error.

You could try a macro as follows:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceAll()
  dim ws as worksheet
  dim fnd as variant
  dim rplc as variant

  
  fnd = "Ott"
  rplc = "10"

  for each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.Replace What:=fnd , Replacement:=rplc , _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase := False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:= False
  next ws
End sub
```

Now, of course you would need to do this for each month. This can be done either by looping through lists, or just changing it all 11 times. As it is just 2 variables to change, I would suggest doing the latter as it would most likely be faster.

Comment: Run-time error '1004' arose. However, above posted code did the trick for me.

Comment: This one works, but doesn't fix the issue as I still receive screwed dates were some days are switched to the months and viceversa